# Self-replication in the genome in the seed

Tags: dna

Is the genome in the seeds of the plant turned off?  That is, does the DNA in the seed not self-replicate?
My second question is, what are the cells feeding on inside the seed before it is planted?

Comment: What makes you think that DNA replication is repressed in seeds?

Comment: @user438383 — He doesn’t say he thinks that, he’s asking. Seems a reasonable question, but one which I imagine an Internet search would answer.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). See also this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework. Finally, please only ask one question at a time. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

DNA in cells in general replicates when cell division occurs (unless it is a cell that contains many nuclei or multiple copies of its own genome, in which case DNA would replicate as copies are made. Multinucleate cells include things like [the mycelium of fungi](https://ec.asm.org/content/14/1/78), and [here is an example](https://www.nature.com/news/2008/080508/full/news.2008.806.html) of a bacterium with thousands of copies of its own genome).

As long as a plant embryo is developing, then the cells are dividing and the DNA is replicated. You might be thinking of the stage of [seed dormancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_dormancy); insofar as during this stage the embryo is no longer growing, cells aren't dividing and therefore DNA is indeed not replicated. I don't know whether we could say the genome is "turned off" however, DNA's role isn't just being replicated, more importantly its role is to be transcribed into RNA which leads to the proteins the cell needs to function being created. I couldn't find whether DNA transcription happens during cell dormancy but it's plausible enough that it is at least slowed down as well. The cells presumably don't have much to do during this period and you wouldn't want them to do much, to conserve energy.

Seeds contain nutrients that can feed the embryo until it can feed itself (for plants that is the moment when they germinate enough to photosynthesize). That is where flour comes from!